# How to open CSV file location using only default explorer

Tags: java, android, csv

Is it possible to open a file's location using only the default explorer (e.g. "My Files") in Android? I know how to open it using other explorers, but it must work on any device assuming it doesn't have an external file explorer.

I would like some guidance in how to code this functionality into my app.

Comment: Android doesn't really have a "default explorer". The Storage Access Framework and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` allow the user to find a document across various storage providers, and so it is reminiscent of a file explorer. But it is not a separate app, and the Storage Access Framework only exists on Android 4.4+.

Answer (score 0):

Because a csv file is just seperated by either ',' or ';' you should just read it inside your application and show the output inside your application. Because the default file explorer does not have a viewer for this.